# Change enclosing quotes in Vim

Tags: python, vim, surround

In Vim, it's a quick 3-character command to change what's inside the current quoted string (e.g., ci"), but is there a simple way to change what type of quotes are currently surrounding the cursor?

Sometimes I need to go from "blah" to """blah""" or "blah" to 'blah' (in Python source code) and I'd ideally like to do it quickly using default key bindings.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) plugin. I find it an essential addition to any vim installation.

Comment: To go from quotes to triple-quotes, do `ysa""wysa""`. It is worth putting in a macro or binding it. For example, `:noremap <C-c> :normal ysa""wysa""<CR>` will bind this to `Ctrl`+`c`. Alternatively, you can just map `:noremap <C-c> :normal ysiw"w<CR>` to surround any one word with quotes, and then press `Ctrl`+`c` or whatever your binding is *n* times to add *n* sets of quotes.

Comment: I've been using vi since 1980 and ya learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

Surround.vim is great, but I don't think it'll handle your triple-quoted needs directly.

The way I've done stuff along these lines (when surround wasn't appropriate) was to use `%`, make the change, then double-backtick to go back to the starting point.  E.g. if the cursor is somewhere in a single-quoted string, do `f'%`, make the change, then double-backtick and `.`.

Comment: Didn't know about double backtick, I would have taken the same approach except I would have made a throwaway mark. +1.